# Scraping a table: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, screen-scraping

I am new to python. I am using it in a jupyter notebooks to scrape a table from Wikipedia. All the code I wrote works, except when I want to put the information into a csv file. The error that appears is "Index list index out of range".

Here is the code:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)'

import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(url, timeout=10)
response

table_id = 'main'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8'))

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': table_id})
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': table_id})
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    print(col[0].find('a').contents[0]) 
    print(col[1].string) #name
    print(col[2].string)
    print(col[3].string)
    print(col[4].string)
    print(col[5].find(text=True))

csvfile = open('population.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

headers = ('COUNTRY','CONTINENT','SUBREGION', 'POPULATION_2018', 'POPULATION_2019', 'CHANGE')
csvwriter.writerow(headers)

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': table_id})
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    country = col[0].find('a').contents[0]
    continent = col[1].string
    subregion = col[2].string
    population_2018 = col[3].string
    population_2019 = col[4].string
    change = col[5].find(text=True)
    
    parsed_row = (country, continent, subregion, population_2018, population_2019, change)

    csvwriter.writerow(parsed_row)

csvfile.close()
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have two part answers. The easiest way to accomplish your task and where in your code the error is.

Let `pandas` handle the `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` and `csv` for you.

```py
import pandas as pd

URI = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)'
df = pd.read_html(URI)[3]
df.to_csv('population.csv', index=False)
```

`pandas` has `.read_html` that returns a list of all tables in the webpage. Your table was at index 3. With that, I saved it with `.to_csv`.

With `.read_html`, you can pass the attributes of a specific table e.g. `attrs = {'id': 'table'}`

```py
# the table is now at index 0
df = pd.read_html(URI, attrs={'id':'main'})[0]
```

You can also specify the parser that will be used by BeautifulSoup that `.read_html` calls:

```py
df = pd.read_html(URI, attrs={'id':'main'}, flavor='lxml')[0] 
# 'lxml' is known for speed. But you can use `html.parser` if `lxml` or `html5lib` are not installed.
```

See more documentation [.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

## Update: Debugging You’re Code

The error from your code is from empty col. using if conditions solves the problem:

```py
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)'

import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(url, timeout=10)
response

table_id = 'main'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8'))

csvfile = open('population.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

headers = ('COUNTRY','CONTINENT','SUBREGION', 'POPULATION_2018', 'POPULATION_2019', 'CHANGE')
csvwriter.writerow(headers)

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': table_id})
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    # this is all that was missing
    if col:
        country = col[0].find('a')['title']
        continent = col[1].string
        subregion = col[2].string
        population_2018 = col[3].string
        population_2019 = col[4].string
        change = col[5].find(text=True)
    
    parsed_row = (country, continent, subregion, population_2018, population_2019, change)
    csvwriter.writerow(parsed_row)

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Prayson, I will try the second solution you mentioned. It looks easier as it is shorter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Prayson W. Daniel has already given the answer, and I offer another way.

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)'

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get(url, timeout=10)

rows = []
headers = ('COUNTRY','CONTINENT','SUBREGION', 'POPULATION_2018', 'POPULATION_2019', 'CHANGE')
rows.append(headers)

table_id = 'main'

doc = SimplifiedDoc(res.text)
table = doc.select('table#'+table_id) # Get the table by id.

trs = table.tbody.children.children[1:] # Get all data rows
for tr in trs:
  row = [tr[0].a.text] # First col, get first link
  row.extend(tr.text[1:]) # Left cols
  rows.append(row)

utils.save2csv('test_wiki.csv', rows) # Save data to csv
```